# File Management | Extract a specific file type and it's folder name and move them to another location with the files stored separately by folder names

Tags: r, excel, file-management

I'm cleaning and organizing a messy folder with all kinds of folders mixed together, I could just go into each folder and create file type specific folders like \images, \videos, etc. But there are many folders for me to dive in and create folders one by one.

I would like to program this process, especially the part extract the file and the folder they are in and create the folder with the same and contains only one type of file.

For example, the existing folder is:

```
~FolderName1
image1.jpg
image2.jpg
image3.png
file.pdf
```

Extract the image files including .jpg and .png and put them under another folder

```
~ImageFolder
 ~FolderName1
 image1.jpg
 image2.jpg
 image3.png
~ReportFolder
 ~FolderName1
 file.pdf
```

I'm open to do this through either R or Excel spreadsheet.

How exactly should I do this?

Thanks

I tried using Excel get data function to identify the locations of images. I expect to complete the moving and creating folder process to be programmed to save time, either through R or Excel

Comment: Please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451) for an implementation with any tool or process, make an earnest effort at solution, then ask a specific question regarding your attempt.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.